# cant refactor color with shade in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I am trying to refactor my code. This is my Code ,I am getting Problem

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.buttnoAction,
      this.buttonColor = Colors.grey[300], // the error getting is " The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. " 
      required this.iconLogo,
      this.iconSize = 15,})
      : super(key: key);

  final void Function() buttnoAction;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final IconData iconLogo;
  final double iconSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: buttnoAction,
        icon: Icon(
          iconLogo,
          color: buttonColor,
          size: iconSize,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here I don't get an error while using `Colors.grey` but can't use `Colors.grey[300]` how to fix this.
why I am getting this error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure but it is probably because Colors.grey is a const (a constant) and Colors.grey[300] is not a const and therefore not accepted as default value of an optional parameter.

If you still want to use Colors.grey[300] as default value, you need to make it a const, this can be done by using the corresponding color code:

```
const Color(0xFFE0E0E0)
```

so change this

```
this.buttonColor = Colors.grey[300],
```

into this

```
this.buttonColor = const Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
this.buttonColor = Colors.grey,
```

or,

```
this.buttonColor =Color(0xFFE0E0E0) //This is equal to grey[w300]
```

for more details https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#non_constant_default_value

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).